# Excel VBA - RegExp - "Test" operation works, but "Execute" operation does not

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Please see the following code:

```
Sub CountAndHighlightProblematicCells()

Dim RegExpo As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[^\u0020-\u007E]"
Dim specialCharactersFound As Object


Dim strInput As String
Dim counter As Long

RegExpo.Global = True
RegExpo.MultiLine = True
RegExpo.IgnoreCase = False
RegExpo.Pattern = strPattern

counter = 0

For Each cell In Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A100")
    strInput = Worksheets(1).Range(cell.Address).Value
    If (RegExpo.Test(strInput)) Then
        Worksheets(1).Range(cell.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
    Set specialCharactersFound = RegExpo.Execute(strInput)

Next

MsgBox ("Number of affected cells: " & counter)
MsgBox ("Number of special characters found: " & specialCharactersFound.Count)

End Sub
```

For some reason, the test operation works as expected, but the execute operation does not.

If you think that it has something to do with the for loop, I checked and it does not - the execute operation does not work as expected even when The focus in on one cell only.

What am I doing wrong? I'm not very experienced with VBA generally and RegExp 
specifically.

Thanks in advance,

Kurkum

Comment: What is the sample string to test? With any Unicode symbol? I cannot repro, `Execute` matches the Unicode character.

Comment: As written your code will only give the count from the last cell checked, whether or not it contains any special characters.

Comment: Actually, the `specialCharactersFound` will always contain the last "special" character.

Comment: What do you mean by _the execute operation does not work as expected_ ?  I've run your code, it runs without error.  What results do you expect?

Comment: The sample string can be "ƒ" (ASCII Code 159), for example.

Well, how can I make the specialCharactersFound object collect all the special characters found and not only the last special character?

Let's say, for example, that if "A1" cell contains the text "ƒ" and cell "A2" cell contatins the text "á", I expect to get the following messages:

"Number of affected cells: 2"
"Number of special characters found: 2"

With the current code, the second message refers to 0 instead of 2.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `Set specialCharactersFound = RegExpo.Execute(strInput)` should be inside your `If` block. More importantly though - VBScript RegExp object doesn't work like java regex for example - you need to save the result of the match each time to another collection otherwise it will be overwritten with each iteration.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, it won't. It will contain **all** special characters from the last cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding these 2 lines to variable declarations:

```
Dim specialCharactersFound As New Collection
Dim mtch As Object
```

and then, instead of the code between `counter = 0` and `Next`, use

```
counter = 0
Set specialCharactersFound = New Collection ' Initialize the collection for special chars

For Each cell In Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A100")
    strInput = Worksheets(1).Range(cell.Address).Value
    Set mtch = RegExpo.Execute(strInput)  ' Find the matches
    For Each objMatch In mtch             ' Iterate throug the match collection
       specialCharactersFound.Add (mtch(0).Value) ' Add the char found to the collection
    Next
    Worksheets(1).Range(cell.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
    counter = counter + 1   ' Increment the affected cell count
Next
```